# How do I make this into a for loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So basically I am trying to replace this:

```
board = {
        0:[0, 1, 2, 9, 10, 11, 18, 19, 20],
        1:[3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 23],
        2:[6, 7, 8, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26]}
```

with a for loop that will automatically create it. Sorry if this seems obvious, but I'm a bit of a noob and I'm having a lot of trouble with this.

Comment: Please show your attempts, we can help you improve/fix them

Comment: hi is that list following [x,x+1,x+2, x+9,x+(1*9),x+(1*9)+1, x+(1*9)+2]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're generating the first 27 integers (starting at 0) and then grouping them. Let's write it like that.

```
def group_by_threes(n=27, group_count=3):
    # The end result will be a dict of lists. The number of lists
    # is determined by `group_count`.
    result = {}
    for x in range(group_count):
        result[x] = []
    # Since we're using subgroups of 3, we iterate by threes:
    for x in range(n // 3):
        base = 3 * x
        result[x % 3] += [base, base + 1, base + 2]
    # And give back the answer!
    return result
```

This code could be made better by making the size of groups (three in this case) an argument, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader. ;)

The advantage of this method is that it's much more modular and adaptable than just writing a one-off method that generates the exact list you're looking for. After all, if you only wanted to ever generate that one list you showed, then it'd probably be better to hardcode it!

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_list(x):
    a = [x,x+1,x+2,x+9,x+9+1,x+9+2,x+18,x+18+1,x+18+2]
    return a
output = {}
for i in range(3):
    output[i*3] = create_list(i*3)

print output
```

please try this you get desired output

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_list(x):
   res = []
   for i in xrange(0,3):
      for j in xrange(0,3):
         res.append(3*x+ 9*i + j)
   return res

dictionary={}
for i in xrange(0,3):
   dictionary[i]=create_list(i)
print dictionary
```

Result:

```
{0: [0, 1, 2, 9, 10, 11, 18, 19, 20], 1: [3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 23], 2: [6, 7, 8, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26]}
```